# Adding values to a database table from a query result using eloquent or fluent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

```
$query = SubjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::id())->select('subjectlist_name')->get();
```

The query above produces these results from Table One:

```
[{"subjectlist_name":football},{"subjectlist_name":cricket},
{"subjectlist_name":tennis},{"subjectlist_name":f1}]
```

I have another table that looks like this:

Table Two

```
ID|second_user_id|topic    |mark(enum '0','1')
1 | 2            |football |0
2 | 2            |tennis   |0
3 | 2            |f1       |0
4 | 2            |Rugby    |0
```

I now want to iterate through my query result and check for matching topics and mark those that do match so that my second table looks like this:

Table Two

```
ID|second_user_id|topic    |mark(enum '0','1')
1 | 2            |football |1
2 | 2            |tennis   |1
3 | 2            |f1       |1
4 | 2            |Rugby    |0
```

The problem I have is that i'm unsure how many `subjectlist_name`'s to expect hence wondering whether there is an elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It does depend a bit on the load you're expecting. If this is for a rare usecase and you do not have heavy traffic on your site, then I would probably consider using an SQL query like this:

```
update second_table_name set mark = 1 and second_user_id= <??> where topic in (select subjectlist_name from first table where user_id=<??>)
```

this should generally do what you want although this will not be performant. If this happens more than once every 10 seconds (and/or you've got some serious other traffic going on), then you might want to iterate in chunks over table one and do update clauses with

```
... where topic in ("f1", "...")
```

however, in that case, please note, you should be having some indexes going on for doing those operations.

Also please consider that "unsure how many subjectlist_names to expect": just check out an approximate number: is it possible that there could be above 1000? if no, then you will probably not need to chunk anyways. This will make the code simpler and easier to understand for everyone.

Comment: ok I see where you're coming from. Im just prototyping so I guess the subject names would be a low number such as 15 for example. I was hoping you could give the the proper syntax for you answer above because im having problems implementing.